# c++ получение данных содержащих кириллицу из oracle через ODBC

Tags: c++, кодировка, oracle, odbc

В БД Oracle хранятся данные в которых присутствует кириллица, CHARACTERSET CL8MSWIN1251. Забираю посредством ODBC, вместо кириллицы - знаки вопроса.

```
std::string kOdbcWrapper::KSQLStatement::getFieldAsString(unsigned short nsColNum)
{
   SQLINTEGER nRlDataSz = 0;
   const unsigned int nBufSize = 256;
   char cBuff[nBufSize]={0};
   std::string sRetStr;

   RETCODE rc = SQLGetData(m_hldStmt->getHandle(), nsColNum,SQL_C_CHAR,cBuff,nBufSize,&nRlDataSz);
   if (rc==SQL_SUCCESS||rc==SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
   {
      sRetStr = cBuff;
      return sRetStr;
   }
   if (nRlDataSz>0)
   {
      SQLINTEGER nVecBufSz = nRlDataSz+1;
      std::vector<char> vBuff(nVecBufSz, 0);
      rc = SQLGetData(m_hldStmt->getHandle(), nsColNum, SQL_C_CHAR,
         reinterpret_cast<SQLCHAR *>(&vBuff.front()), nVecBufSz, &nRlDataSz);
      if (rc==SQL_SUCCESS||rc==SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
         return std::string(&vBuff[0], vBuff.size());
   }
   return sRetStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема берёт начало из-за несоответствия кодировок клиента и сервера. Кодировки проверяются через `SELECT * nls_session_parameters` и `SELECT * nls_database_parameters` соответственно. Необходимо проверить наличие переменной окружения `NLS_LANG` на клиенте, и в случае её отсутствия установить её. В моём случае база была в кодировке `AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251` установив такую же кодировку в `NLS_LANG` проблема ушла